# To get a column name using the column value

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `AccountDetails` with some miscellaneous columns no_1,no_2,no_3. I will be giving some label values in any of these columns. For e.g. 'Number of accounts'. How can I find out the column name which has this label 'Number of accounts'.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me (or anyone else, it would seem) what you're trying to accomplish here. Please see this post and consider editing your question. [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Please provide an example with details and expected output you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN no_1='Number of accounts' THEN 'no_1'
  WHEN no_2='Number of accounts' THEN 'no_2'
  WHEN no_3='Number of accounts' THEN 'no_3'
END AS ColumnName
FROM MyTable
```